# How to build statically against musl-libc on gentoo (glibc profile) and clang?

Tags: clang, llvm, static-linking, gentoo, musl

I'm not sure if this belongs on superuser instead of stackoverflow, at least for the first part, but for starters, how do I install `sys-libs/musl` (or any other alt `libc` for that matter) without replacing glibc or switching to the musl profile; secondly, how do I tell `clang` to statically link against this library (or, again, any other alt `libc`) as opposed to the system `libc` (`sys-libs/glibc`)?

Answer (score 2):

You can't install `sys-libs/musl` next to `sys-libs/glibc`, because these ebuild are intended to be used for the system's libc. I'd recommend to download [the most recent version of musl](http://www.musl-libc.org/download.html) and then compile/install it locally using `make && make install`. Musl provides `musl-gcc` which uses the locally installed musl libc during compilation/linking. As for `clang`, see http://wiki.musl-libc.org/wiki/BuildingLLVM.